# How to fix error "org.apache.axis cannot resolved to a type"?

Tags: java

When I build my program, it gives the error:

> org.apache.axis cannot resolved to a type

I've seen on some sites that this may be because of enum type which is not there in the latest version of jdk. Currently I'm using jdk 1.6.x. How can I overcome the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`org.apache.axis` isn't a type anyway - it's a package. However, the types within that package are provided by the [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) project. You'll need to download the libraries and add them to your classpath; the exact details will depend on whether you're using an IDE, the command line, Ant or whatever.

Note that Axis 1 is rather old now... you may wish to consider migrating to a more modern web-service platform.

Comment: Jon can you give me the link where i can download libraries i'm using eclipse indigo and 'm new to this environment and lang.

Comment: @nag: I provided a link in my answer. But if you're new to Java I would *strongly* advise you not to jump in at the deep end. Start off with simpler projects. If you try to dive right in with web services, you'll get lost extremely quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll follow your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

What this means is that the compiler hasn't got a clue on where to find `org.apache.axis`, so to solve it you should let the compiler know where to find it.

Here's [a good link](http://java.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=Cannot_resolve_type) to read a bit up on this particular kind of error (Cannot resolve type).